# Yii Php - Hiding or showing column based on data value from other column

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm currently having trouble with bootstrap to display some columns in a GridView.

I have this in my code:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id' => 'viewrank-grid',
        'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'cssFile' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . "/css/cgridview.css",
    'dataProvider' => $rank_model->search(),
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'header' => 'rank_id',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'rank_title',
            'header' => 'Rank',
        ),
        array(
            'header' => 'Access',
            'value' => 'Privilege::model()->findByAttributes(array(\'module_id\'=>' . $module_model->id . ',\'rank_id\'=>$data->id)) ? \'Allowed\': \'Not Allowed\'',
        ),     
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{view}&nbsp;{allow}&nbsp;{deny}',
            'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '10%;', 'style' => 'text-align: center'),
            'buttons' => array(
                'view' => array(
                    'label'=>'View', 
                        'imageUrl' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . "/images/gridview_icons/view.png",
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("management/viewrank",array("id"=>$data->id))',
                ),
                'allow' => array(
                    'label'=>'Allow', 
                        'imageUrl' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . "/images/gridview_icons/approve.png",
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("management/allowmodule",array("rank_id"=>$data->id,"module_id"=>' . $module_model->id . '))',
                    'visible' => '!(Privilege::model()->findByAttributes(array(\'module_id\'=>' . $module_model->id . ',\'rank_id\'=>$data->id)))',
                ),
                'deny' => array(
                    'label'=>'Deny', 
                        'imageUrl' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . "/images/gridview_icons/delete.png",
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("management/denymodule",array("rank_id"=>$data->id,"module_id"=>' . $module_model->id . '))',
                    'visible' => 'Privilege::model()->findByAttributes(array(\'module_id\'=>' . $module_model->id . ',\'rank_id\'=>$data->id))',
                )

            )
        )

    ),
));
```

and this is the view of that bootstrap.
[image]

is there a way that i can add a condition where if rank_id = 2 then the [image] icon is hidden.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change your visible condition in your CButtonColumn allow button

```
 'visible' => '(($data->id) && 
       !(Privilege::model()->findByAttributes(array(\'module_id\'=>' . 
          $module_model->id . ',\'rank_id\'=>$data->id))))',
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that rank_id is a field that exists in the data provider, so it will be available in $data object:

```
'visible' => '($data->rank_id!=2)',
```